# How can I center a paragraph element that is bigger than its container using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to center the following paragraph element (email) that is bigger than its container:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
        <a href="mailto:{{ site.email }}">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-3x wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay=".1s"></i>
            <p>{{ site.email }}</p>
        </a>
    </div>
```

I have tried to use text-center directly on my paragraph element, which doesn't work, how can I center this element?

Comment: try `d-flex justify-content-center` on `p`

Comment: There are few options, decrease text size, override p width and margin hardcoding it, a combination of both, use smaller text that fits or use flex.

Comment: @TemaniAfif it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to achieve it. What I prefer is with position.

- make sure that the container or the parent element has a position relative.
- add these style attributes to the paragraph
  `position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

I hope this is going to help you